# What are the lyrics for the opening music?

Tags: trials-evolution

I've noticed that there are a few versions of the rap that plays when you first launch Trials Evolution. How many versions are there? What are the lyrics for each version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are *at least* 3 different versions.  Although, I couldn't verify the exact answer to this question, here is what I have found to be a close verification to it:

> **Song 1:**
>   Give me the keys to this motorcycle let me start up
>   yeaaaaaaaah
>   vroom vroom im ready to go
>   time to let the mo mo mo monday night stroll
>   this is the moment you've been waiting for
>   lock up the basement and the front door
>   noone coming in
>   time to time trials
>   im getting ready baby im racing all night and while
>   everybody here is waiting to play my highscore stands all day
>   yeah here we go
>   do not hold me back
>   do not try to ride on the back of my motorcycle
>
> **Song 2:**
>   I think theres something you should know about me, I just happen to....
>   like trials i like danger i like fire i like nitro i like getting it wild
>   i like a bit of blast i like taking it fast i like going to the end and doing it with no class
>   trust trust trust trust me on this
>   the moment you've been waiting for kiss kiss kiss of death
>   and ill meet you at the next step but you cant make it so baby get in line i guess
>   where im coming from, from all sides high above fire flakes (????) monday nitro
>
> **Song 3 - (Very hard for me to understand him)**
>   Whenever I'm riding, I'm always extra careful and I like to...
>   Burn my tires hotter than hell
>   You can always smell the rubber burnin' as well
>   Be on the limit and stop when im going safe
>   Destruction Devastation thats my play
>   Welcome home
>   put your feet up lets begin
>   time trials is ready bu-bu-bu-bu-bu baby its in
>   ready fast the full gear flyin 
>   through the sky nitro is burning you're dyin
>   this is the mo mo mo mo moment you been waiting for
>   nitro time trials need i say more

Comment: I heard the soundtrack to this game is bad, but this... this is something completely different...

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It looks like there's at least one other intro rap (see here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QARQsvf9v0M&src_vid=JUtSiE0jwWQ). I wonder if there are even more than four.

Comment: @Brysonic Hope it helped!

Comment: The word "hell" is faded out in "Song 3" I think and this is likely so that the game meets the criteria for a young audience.

Answer (score 3):

Foxtrot did a terrific job of transcribing the lyrics for the first three intros, so I'd like to contribute my version of the fourth one:

**Voice 1**:

```
Hmm, did you say Monday nitro? 
This looks like a great game, do you mind if I give it a sho-
```

**Voice 2**:

```
Shut up, sucka! It's time to begin 
Light the hot metal of fire and sin 
We're burning and the bikes are flying through the air 
Beat my high score and I'll beat you again
That's the tie (?), get ready for the moment you've been 
Waiting for and the nitro is burning down your door
Who's there? Knock, knock, pizza party all day. 
Friday night quench your thirst and stay
Over for a sleep over. Time trials trials 
Everybody is here, now we can't stop.
```

Also, here are the links to the Youtube videos:

[Intro 1](http://youtu.be/JUtSiE0jwWQ),
[Intro 2](http://youtu.be/3UTrftZSjTw),
[Intro 3](http://youtu.be/QARQsvf9v0M) (The one in my answer),
[Intro 4](http://youtu.be/HWFQU2SaUiY)